# Python Locust - herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host

Tags: python, locust

I'm trying to test my application using python Locust, but I can't get a basic version to work. My locustfile.py file:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def test_get(self):
        self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait=5000
    max_wait=9000
```

I ran

```
locust --host=http://example.com
```

And got this error:

```
[2015-08-04 23:10:11,734] my-macbook-pro.local/ERROR/stderr: herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

Wondering if it's just me putting in the wrong host, I tried facebook, google, and other hosts with no success either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you literally run `locust --host=http://example.com`?

Comment: Ha no, I did my server name. Stackoverflow won't let me put in urls besides example.com

Comment: I just had to ask. The error indicates some kind of name resolution problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it could be? I can't see anything wrong with it

Comment: The address works in other programs, e.g. browser or curl?

Comment: Yep definitely works there too. Like I said, I tried facebook and google urls also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `-f locustfile.py` parameters for running a file: `locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://www.example.com`

Alternatively, you can also declerate the host in locust class like in the below and run it `locust -f locustfile.py`:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

  @task(1)
  def test_get(self):
    self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
  task_set = UserBehavior
  host = "http://www.example.com"
  min_wait=5000
  max_wait=9000
```